# update quantity of input box specific to each id using session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am making a shopping cart using arrays and sessions.

I would like to update the quantity of an item that has a specific id number, without updating the other quantities which have different id number.

My code is bellow and to run it, you must get id from URL.

So just put ?id=1 in front of the .php in the address bar (as I am sure everyone is aware of more than me).

**Cart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

// set the array and store in session

$_SESSION['items'][]=array(     
                        'id'=>"'".$_GET['id']."'",
                        'qty'=> 1                            
                    ); 

// Display each array value stored in the session

foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $value) {

    // Display the id
    echo 'The ID is ' ."''''" . $value['id'] ."''''" ;
    // Display the Qty
    echo 'the QTY  ' ."''''" . $value['qty'] ."''''" ;

    echo "<br/>";

    //Echo a form that displays the Qty in a input box,
    // My problem is that, I cant update the qty value in the input box where each id is different.
    echo "<form method='post' action='id.php' name='edit'>

    <p>Quantity:  <input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" name='".$value['id']."' value='".$value['qty']."'/> </p><br>            

    <input class='save' name='update' value='update' type='submit'>

    </form>";

}
// check if the update button is submited so that the qty value can be changed where the id number of the selected qty input box is edited
if (isset($_POST["update"])) {
    $_SESSION['item'][$id]= $_POST["'".$value['id']."'"];
}
else
{  
    echo "quantity is updated";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sugesstion from my side is, store cart products in database not in session.

Comment: But what about people who just put items in the cart and then abandon the website and buy nothing?

Comment: what if i add 2 products, and come back after a week to purchase it??

Comment: You're right that would be a good reason to store it in data base. But its not possible to store more than one item under the same session token in a data base table. If I store it in database, then i have to make a new table for every session token" every new user"

Comment: Use AJAX for forms. You'll have to learn it eventually.

Comment: I will definitely learn it later on. But for now, there should be a way to update quantity for each id. Is it really impossible with php?

Comment: any other ideas anyone ? -Hassan Althaf

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are making a `$_SESSION['items']` Array of Arrays, change

```
$_SESSION['items'][]
```

to

```
$_SESSION['items']
```

Otherwise, you'll need a loop within your loop.

Right now, `$value` in

```
foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $value) {
```

really represents an Array, which has your other Array in it. Additionally, you should not have more than one form with the same name. Don't put a form in a loop unless you're changing the name at each step of the loop.

Comment: Okay, what about being able to update the quantity using the input box for the quantity from 1 to any other value for each specific id ???

Comment: @Tom The loop part is only about the variable name, I have posted a solution.

Comment: @PHPglue I think what he has done is right, I've tested it.

Comment: He's storing an array of data containing the id and quantity of each item, as an array inside an array.

Comment: Obviously you don't get Arrays. It would have to be `foreach ($_SESSION['items'][0] as $value) {` to work.